# Minecraft Forge Gradlew JAVA_HOME error

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to make a mod for MC, and I am watching a tutorial that says:
`You have to set Path to the JDK space, and then you can test if you done it right if you type "javac" into cmd.`
I have done this, and it works. But if i try to run

```
gradlew setupDevWorkspace eclipse
```

It returns an error:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':makeStart'.

  > Unable to find a javac compiler;
  >   com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
  >   Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
  >   It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121"

I am using windows 7.
Thank You for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JAVA_HOME` points to a JRE, not a JDK. A JRE comes without a compiler but you need one.

Install a JDK and then re-set the variable and have it point to the JDK installation directory.